# Import Face_recognition gets stuck while using it inside a myfunctions module

Tags: python-3.x, module, face-recognition, dlib

face_recognition version: '1.2.3'
Python version: 3.11
Operating System: Windows 11

Description
For organization purposes i have my functions inside a myfunctionsfolder/module so i can import them from there. But somehow when importing the library it just gets stuck and doesnt raise an exception even. Other functions in the module do work and when i comment out the import for face_recognition the module starts working again. When i copy the exact function script to my main folder so out of the module it works again just fine. Even more weird is that it somehow does work for like one or two face_locations as an example before getting stuck.

```
try:
    import time
    import inspect
    import face_recognition 
    from termcolor import colored

    def find_facelocations_aug(image, file_path, num_up): 
        
        # Get the current function's name for error printing
        func_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
        
        # Initialize counters with dynamic keys
        counters = {
            f'{func_name}_errors_loading': 0,
            f'{func_name}_exceptions': 0,
            'skipped_images': 0,
            f'{func_name}_time_elapsed': 0.0 
        }
        
        try:
            if image is not None:
                start_time = time.time()  # Start timing
                
                # Use face_recognition to locate faces and get encodings
                face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=1, model="hog")
                
                
                # Calculate elapsed time and add to counters
                elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                counters[f'{func_name}_time_elapsed'] = elapsed_time
                
                if len(face_locations) == 1:
                    return face_locations, counters
                else:
                    print(colored(f" No or multiple faces found for {file_path} in {func_name.capitalize()}", 'yellow'))
                    counters['skipped_images'] += 1
                    return None, counters
            else:
                print(colored(f" Error loading image for {file_path} in {func_name.capitalize()}", 'red'))
                counters['skipped_images'] += 1
                counters[f'{func_name}_errors_loading'] += 1
                return None, counters
        except Exception as e:
            print(colored(f"{func_name.capitalize()} failed for {file_path}: {e}", 'red'))
            counters['skipped_images'] += 1
            counters[f'{func_name}_exceptions'] += 1
            return None, counters
except Exception as e:
    print(colored(f"An error occured while importing: {e}", 'red'))
```

What I Did
I have tried eveything i could think of before realising it is because of the import. And since i have tried preloading it in my main script but i just cant think of other possible resolutions

Comment: Well, try to reinstall face_recognition module, check if face_recognition_models is installed too..